# How to manually trigger webpack bundling?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, elm

I have a medium size elm app. Most of my changes revolve around refactoring and other : `"nothing to show in the browser"` - changes.

On each save the webpack process starts again.The **bundling + browser refresh takes around 8-15 seconds**. During this time **my processor gets to 100%** and the **editor freezes**, i **can't even scroll** the code. (3.7Gh i3 processor, 4GB RAM)

When doing small changes and saving - this wait is overkill. So i try to do many changes before a save. But saving is nice because i get the code formatting.

Without the script webpack running - **the compilation of elm code + code formatting takes less then 3 seconds**, even for very big refactoring.

Currently i'm stooping the webpack script when i don't need to see something in the browser, and i start it again once i need to view something. This **initial build takes between 40 - 60 seconds** .. so starting and stooping it's pretty painful.

To solve this, I would like to trigger the bundling and browser refresh manually - by pressing F5 or something.

And keep only `the compilation`, and `code formatting` stuff on `ctrl + s / save`

I don't exactly understand how `saving-compilation-browser refresh` are triggering one another here. I also have editor packages(atom) for compilation and code formatting - they work fine without webpack running.

Maybe they work independently and the webpack script starts because of file changes.

But if this assumption is correct - then why i get the error messages and the compilation messages inside my dev-server console when webpack is running? Webpack seems to do code compilation independently..

I **turned off the watch mode** inside `webpack.config.js` but it doesn't work. **It's like nothing has changed**.

This is my config :

```
module.exports = {
    watch: false,

    entry: entryPath,

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: outputPath
    },

    module: {

        rules: [{
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.elm$/,
                exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
                use: 
                    [ 'elm-hot-loader'
                    , 'elm-webpack-loader?verbose=true&warn=true&debug=true'
                    ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader', 'postcss-loader'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: extractSASS.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            }

        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index_.html',
            inject: 'body',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        extractCSS,
        extractSASS
    ]
};
```

Question: **how can i trigger this bundling and browser refresh by pressing a specific key (F5 maybe)?** and stop it from automatically watching the file system?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Damn, that's a long wait. What command do you currently use to start webpack? If there's a `-w` parameter in there somewhere, that's your culprit. I refrain from using some plugins during development, because they substantially slow down the webpack bundling process on my end. The compiling and webpack bundling seems just about instant when the plugins aren't doing their thing.

Comment: i'm running with the build script which is `"build": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",`